# Search option for contact names that extends base adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, baseadapter

I am trying to implement search option for my contact list that is being displayed with Contact images and contact name.

I have created a text box to input the search text.

**contactnameadpater.java: extends base adapter.**

which has the following code:

```
 public class ContactNamesAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable
  {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> originalData;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filteredData;



    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

  public ContactNamesAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d)
   {
    activity = a;
    originalData=d;


     inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 }

public int getCount() 
{       
    return originalData.size();         
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{

    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_row, null);


    ImageView profile  = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.ContactImage);                 
    Uri my_contact_Uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(originalData.get(position).get("id")));
    InputStream photo_stream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ContactNamesAdapter.inflater.getContext().getContentResolver(),my_contact_Uri);            
    if(photo_stream != null) 
    {
        BufferedInputStream buf =new BufferedInputStream(photo_stream);
        Bitmap my_btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
        profile.setImageBitmap(my_btmp);

    }
    else
    {
        profile.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_pic);
    }

    TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setText(originalData.get(position).get("name"));   

    return vi;

}


@Override
public Filter getFilter()
{
    return new Filter()
    {
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filteredResultsData;

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence)
        {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            //If there's nothing to filter on, return the original data for your list
            if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0)
            {
                results.values = originalData;
                results.count = originalData.size();
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> filterResultsData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

                for(HashMap<String,String> data : originalData)
                {

                    if(originalData == filterResultsData )
                    {
                        filterResultsData.add(data);

                    }

                }            

                results.values = filterResultsData;
                results.count = filteredResultsData.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults)
        {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>)filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

**contactname.java: extends an activity.**

OnCreate:

```
DetailsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    contactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ContactNamelist);

    profileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ContactImage);

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    getContactName();

            contactList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());  
            //adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            Log.e("getfilter","getfilter");
            contactList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
    });

}
```

and under **getContactName()**:

```
      public void getContactName()
    {
    final Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    final String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID
    };


    String selection  = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '1'";
    final String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection,  null, sortOrder);

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) 
    {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) 
        {
            String Sid = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("name", name);
            map.put("id", Sid);

            DetailsList.add( map);

        }
    }
    cur.close(); 


    adapter = new ContactNamesAdapter(this, DetailsList); 

    // updating listview
    contactList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The problem is that I am not getting results after typing the text in search box. I am not sure where I am going wrong?

Let me know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this link. 
[Click Here to see Searchview](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/android-searchview-tutorial-edittext-with-phone-contacts-search-and-autosuggestion/)

It is a good SearchView or use my SearchView below
Here is my search method on a listview

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { //search is a edittext object

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                textlength = search.getText().length(); //textlength is a global variable

                filtered_text = new ArrayList<RowItem>(); //global array list
                for (int i = 0; i < employee.length(); i++)
                {

                    if(rowItems.get(i).getTitle().toString().toUpperCase().contains(search.getText().toString().toUpperCase())) //rowItem is an object of my holder class for Custom Adapter
                    {
                     //Adding image and names which match the search criteria 
                       in filtered_text array list
                                String mDrawableName;
                                try {
                                    mDrawableName = employee.getJSONObject(i).getString("image");
                                    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
                                    RowItem item = new RowItem(resID, rowItems.get(i).getTitle());
                                    filtered_text.add(item);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                            }


                        }
                        adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(YourClass.this, filtered_text);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                            int after) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
```

Comment: The option you are talking about works only on Api level more than 11...I am using a minimum API of 9

Comment: What option ? What about the code above. It does not have any element that require api level >= 11